# Error "The request body could not be read while attempting to parse it as JSON"

Tags: php, json

Our developer is having a little problem with an API (Brightpearl) and receiving a "The request body could not be read while attempting to parse it as JSON" message when trying to run the below script. Does anyone have any ideas on the possible issue? Many thanks in advance.

```
<?php
define ("DB_HOST","localhost");
define ("DB_USER","busi6292_REMOVED");
define ("DB_PASSWORD","REMOVED");
define ("DB_DATABASE","busi6292_REMOVED");

$link = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . @mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db (DB_DATABASE);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

// Brightperl Data Access Start

    $authenticationDetails = array(
    'apiAccountCredentials' => array(
        'emailAddress' => 'REMOVED',
        'password'     => 'REMOVED',
    ),
    );
    $encodedAuthenticationDetails = json_encode($authenticationDetails);
    $authenticationUrl = 'https://ws-eu1.brightpearl.com/REMOVED/authorise';

    //$cresponse_token=getdata($url,$authenticationDetails);

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authenticationUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($authenticationDetails));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (false === $response) {
        echo 'Request unsuccessful' . PHP_EOL;
        curl_close($ch);
        exit(1);
    }
    $responseCode = (int) curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $responseBody = json_decode($response);
    curl_close($ch);

    $authorisationToken = $responseBody->response;

// End



$sql = "select * from mail where InvoiceDate ='".date('Y-m-d')."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    //print_r($sql_array);

    //echo $authorisationToken; exit;


    // Brigtperl API Access for the Orders has been shipped Start

    $ShippingGoodsoutURL = 'https://ws-eu1.brightpearl.com/2.0.0/REMOVED/warehouse-service/goods-note/goods-out/'.$sql_array['OrderNo'];

    $headers = array(
    "brightpearl-auth: {$authorisationToken}",
    'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT',
    );
    $newShippingWarehouseDetails = array(
    "priority" => false,
    "shipping" => 
    array(
            "reference" =>'"'.$sql_array['InvoiceNumber'].'"',
            ),
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ShippingGoodsoutURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($newShippingWarehouseDetails));


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($newShippingWarehouseDetails));

    $GoodsoutreShippingResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($GoodsoutreShippingResponse);

    //exit;

    // End


}



?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `@mysql_error()`?  Remove those `@`.  You need to handle your errors, not just ignore them.

Comment: Not entirely sure but shouldn't this line -> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($newShippingWarehouseDetails));` be using `json_encode` instead of `http_build_query`. You're passing a `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` type header but passing the data as an encoded url string.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be entirely sure, but I believe your problem lies with the second `curl` request. You're passing a header ->  `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` <- with your request. However, your encoding your data as a url string -> `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($newShippingWarehouseDetails));`.

Try this:

***Change this:***

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($newShippingWarehouseDetails));
```

***to this:***

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($newShippingWarehouseDetails));
```

If the data is properly encoded as JSON, I don't think you should have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for offering but had no luck unfortunately on that change!